# How to store value of variable at specific time steps while MATLAB simulation runs?

Tags: matlab, vector, ode

I am simulating a dynamic system using the `ode15s(..)` MATLAB solver:

```
tspan = 0:0.01:8;
[t,theta] = ode15s(@ode_simulation, tspan, theta)
```

Inside the `ode_simulation(..)` function I am computing a signal `u` which does an exact job. Some lines of this function are these:

```
function d_theta = ode_simulation(t,theta)
    
    ...
    ...
    u = (K*g*s_q)/e;

    d_theta = [theta(2) ; ... ];

end
```

The code executes well but I would like to obtain the values of variable `u` at the specific time instants defined by `tspan`. So, the simulation return a `801x4` matrix for the `theta` solution and I also want a `801x1` vector containing the corresponding `u` values. I tried storing them as the simulation runs but obviously all the values the ODE-Solver obtains throughout all its steps are being stored, resulting in an much bigger vector. How can I store and plot the values of `u` variable at the specific time steps defined by `tspan` ? Here are the links for my code:

[main_code](https://pastebin.com/ySWTM2dj)

[ode_simulation](https://pastebin.com/Nf86WfjN)

```
function h = uniform_hysteretic_quantizer(u,last,D)    
    if (u >= last + D)
        h = last + D;
    elseif (u <= last - D)
        h = last - D;
    else
        h = last;
    end
end
```

Comment: From the `ode15s` you get a vector of `t` and `theta` which are the inputs to `ode_simulation`. Can't you just do the calculation after the solver has done its work using the output of `ode15s` as inputs for `ode_simulation`?

Comment: I tried that and got the error: `Invalid expression. Check for extra or missing characters`.

Comment: Can you show what you did and how? 
The error means that there is a typo or invalid syntac somewhere

Comment: I edited the OP. After the `ode15s(..)` completed, I executed `[~,u(k)] = ode_simulation(t(k),theta(k,:))` inside a `for` loop going from `k=1:numel(t)`.